# How does SSH know which public key to use from authorized_keys?

Tags: ssh-keys

I know this question was asked several times before in StackExchange:[https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/182804/how-does-ssh-know-which-public-key-to-use-from-authorized-keys?noredirect=1&lq=1]
and also in stackoverflow:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580283/how-does-ssh-public-key-authentication-work-picking-up-right-keys[text]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580283/how-does-ssh-public-key-authentication-work-picking-up-right-keys%5Btext%5D)
However, I haven't found any answer that fully satisfied me on the topic.
According to my understanding, when performing an ssh public key authentication, the server sends a challenge to the client using the public key located in .ssh/authorized_keys, which the client decrypts using the private key it has.
What I don't understands is how the server picks the public key for the challenge from all the keys it has in the .ssh/authorized_keys file.

From what I know, the authorized_keys only keeps information about the public keys themselves and the encryption algorithm type for each one of them. Also, I understand that any client in possession of the private key can connect to the server containing the corresponding public key, even if the client doesn't have the public key itself. From what I gathered so far, I see only two possible options for the selection of the right public key:

1. The server 'loops' over the authorized_keys file, and tries to challenge the client with each one of them, until one challenge is responded with a correct answer (and prevents login if no challenge was answered correctly). This method seems improbable due to the extensive computation required for the repeated challenge in case there are many public keys available on the server.
2. The client can retrieve the public key from its private key 'on the spot' during a connection attempt, and sends the public key he wants for the challenge to the server. From what I know, you can't mathematically retrieve the public key from private key alone using RSA or elliptic curves. Nonetheless, I understand that the private key file generated by ssh-keygen contains additional information other than the private key, like the modulus and publicExponent in the case of RSA, which makes it possible to generate the public key, even if the public key file is missing.

In case there is a third option I haven't thought of, I would be more than happy to know.

Comment: The public key is a part of the private key. If you have the private key, you can extract the public key from it (actually multiple, but not really relevant to the question). So the challenger can tell the server what public key it wants to use.

Answer (score 1):

Why guess when you can just read the [protocol specification (RFC 4252, section 7)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252)?

> To avoid unnecessary processing and user interaction, the following
> message is provided for querying whether authentication using the
> "publickey" method would be acceptable.
>
> ```
>   byte      SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST
>   string    user name in ISO-10646 UTF-8 encoding [RFC3629]
>   string    service name in US-ASCII
>   string    "publickey"
>   boolean   FALSE
>   string    public key algorithm name
>   string    public key blob
> ```
>
> The server MUST respond to this message with either
> SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE or with the following:
>
> ```
>   byte      SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_PK_OK
>   string    public key algorithm name from the request
>   string    public key blob from the request
> ```

In other words: the client offers each key in turn and if the server is okay with it, it can try to pass a challenge with that private key.

You also see this if you `ssh -v` to a server:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: $USER/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:<key fingerprint> agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: $USER/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:<key fingerprint> agent
Authenticated to $SERVER ([$ADDRESS]:22) using "publickey".
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the meaning of "the client offers each key in turn". The client needs only one private key to connect, and doesn't have anymore keys to offer

Comment: A client can have an arbitrary amount of keys installed and/or loaded into its SSH agent. For security reasons, the server does not expose the list of accepted keys a priori. Therefore the client must ask the server for every key it has "can I even _try_ to authenticate with this key?"